# How to use "on click" before the creation of my element

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, click

I try to trigger an event on user click, then I used the on click method of JQuery. The problem is that I create my element after my onclick function.
I've read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6658752/click-event-doesnt-work-on-dynamically-generated-elements) or [here](http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/faq/how-to-bind-onclick-event-to-dynamically-added-elements-in-jquery.php) that we can add a balise name between click and the function but my code return `n.apply is not a function`

Here is my JQuery method:

```
d3.selectAll("body")
     .on('click', '.child', function(){
                console.log("here");}
```

and later on,this code return the good elements :

```
console.log(d3.selectAll("body .child"));
```

Comment: is there any console errors on browser? also have you put your code inside `$(document).ready ...`?

Comment: nothing except : n.apply is not a func

Comment: try with `$(document).on('click', '.child', function(){` it may work but this is not proper solution

Comment: what is d3, does it return anything in the time of registering the handlers?

Comment: You can try exporting the handler to a function and assign it as handler. You can now call function anytime once it is defined.

Comment: btw, what is selectAll() function? it is not jQuery

Comment: selectAll is d3
but it works with $(document), thanks @BhushanKawadkar (you can add an answer, I'll accept it)

Comment: happy to help you :), I have added my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this : use `$(document)` as parent element to delegate click event calls

```
$(document).on('click', '.child', function(){
     console.log("here");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a handler while you creating an element. Just create a jQuery OBject and append this to whatever you need. Note: The Click function can also be inline.

```
Example: https://jsfiddle.net/rfccvgLm/
```

Answer (score 0):

it seems - as far as the syntax is ok - that the handlers are not registered, because **d3.selectAll** does not return no elements to register the event on